# SELECT statement for a VIEW in MySQL not returning all the wanted rows

Tags: sql, mysql, drupal, integration, sql-view

I need help with my MySQL query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
    DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
    VIEW users_phpscheduleit
AS
    SELECT 
            u.uid AS memberid,
            pass AS password, 
            mail AS email,
            pv1.value AS fname,
            pv2.value AS lname,
            pv3.value AS phone,
            e_add, e_mod, e_del, e_html, e_app, 
            is_admin, lang, timezone_scheduleit, 
            institution, logon_name
        FROM 
            users u, profile_values pv1, profile_values pv2, profile_values pv3
        WHERE
            u.uid = pv1.uid AND u.uid = pv2.uid AND u.uid = pv3.uid
            AND 
            pv1.fid = 26
            AND
            pv2.fid = 27
            AND 
            pv3.fid = 8;
```

This cannot contain a [list of things](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html), in order for it to remain editable using the view table in an INSERT or UPDATE query in a PHP application I am integrating with another PHP system. My users table is 442 long and I'm only getting 1/2 of them.

**Problem:**
I am not able to get all the rows in the `users` table because they obviously don't all have a `profile_values.fid` of 26, 27 or 8.

Q: How can I tweak the statement to still include those but without breaking [the rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html) that enable editability?

*ps.for the curious I'm trying to authenticate phpScheduleIt users through the Drupal DB*

Comment: I was going to recommend outer joins, but it doesn't appear that those are allowed in editable views either.  You may be asking for the impossible, you're more or less asking the view to "know" that it needs to insert an additional row in the profile_values table to hold a phone number that until now didn't exist.

Comment: Yea I think your right, this seems a little impossible.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to get all the rows in the users table because they obviously don't all have a profile_values.fid of 26, 27 or 8.

That's because your query uses INNER JOINs, when you need to use an OUTER (IE LEFT/RIGHT) JOIN if you want data where there's a possibility of no supporting record.  Your query is in ANSI-89 syntax, which doesn't consistently implement OUTER JOIN syntax.  Here's your query rewritten using ANSI-92 syntax:

```
   SELECT u.uid AS memberid,
          pass AS password, 
          mail AS email,
          pv1.value AS fname,
          pv2.value AS lname,
          pv3.value AS phone,
          e_add, e_mod, e_del, e_html, e_app, 
          is_admin, lang, timezone_scheduleit, 
          institution, logon_name
     FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_VALUES pv1 ON pv1.uid = u.uid
                            AND pv1.fid = 26
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_VALUES pv2 ON pv2.uid = u.uid
                            AND pv2.fid = 27
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_VALUES pv3 ON pv3.uid = u.uid
                            AND pv3.fid = 8
```

Comment: I had the same exact thought, but then I checked and outer joins are not possible with updatable views.

Comment: @gregcase: Just one of the many reasons I consider MySQL to be a crippled database - their view support is underwhelming.

Comment: This is my battle :) ...it's not fun but I'm making compromises.